# How to add browse button in contacts us form

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us

How to add browse button in contacts us form i want to send browse image in contacts us email with browse image.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Mage_Contacts_IndexController class you can see the template is set in there `Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE)` the`XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE` is set to `contacts/email/email_template`. This is set in the configuration area of the admin.

If you head to admin > System > Configuration > Contacts > Email Options you should see the template set in there. In my case this is `Contact Form (Default Template from Locale)`.

This template can be found at  `app/locale/en_US/template/email/contact_form.html`. Simply add the markup you need in there.

Comment: that i know i want to add browse button & then save or upload that image in to server or sent in to an email